# Dynamically get the category name in breadcrumb link via xml

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I need to get the category name and product name in the breadcrumb which i am using in my layout in the link tag:

My Breadcrumb should be:

**Home / Recipes / Category Page / Category detail Page**

First 2 links (Home and Recipes works fine)

```
<recipe_recipe_index>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>

        <action method="unsetChild"><alias>breadcrumbs</alias></action>
        <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="addCrumb" module="recipe" translate="crumbInfo.label crumbInfo.title">
                <crumbName>Home</crumbName>
                <!-- <params helper="module/getHomeUrl" /> -->
                <crumbInfo>
                    <label>Home</label>
                    <title>Go to Home Page</title>
                    <link>index/../../</link>  
                </crumbInfo>
            </action>
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbName>Recipes</crumbName>
                <crumbInfo>
                    <label>Recipes</label>
                    <title>Go to Recipe Home Page</title>
                    <link>index/../</link>
                </crumbInfo>
            </action>
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbName>Category Page</crumbName>
                <crumbInfo>
                    <label>Category Page</label><!--How to give the category name here dynamically -->
                    <title>Category Page</title>
                    <link>  </link> <!--How to give the category how page link dynamically -->
                </crumbInfo>
            </action>
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbName>Category detail Page</crumbName>
                <crumbInfo>
                    <label>Category detail Page</label>
                    <title>Category detail Page</title>
                </crumbInfo>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

Comment: you are trying to get this in product view page ??

Comment: Yes product detail page...i need to use the functions like getCategory() or whatever dynamically  for the <title>Category Name</title> and <link>  </link>

Answer (score 0):

Breadcrumbs are very useful for user navigation. Breadcrumbs for product page, category page, etc. are created by default Magento code.

**The following code will show breadcrumbs created by Magento.**

> You can print the following code anywhere in php or phtml files.

`echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->toHtml();`

You can create you **own breadcrumbs** as well. Like, you may need to create breadcrumbs if you have your own custom built module. I will show you here, how you can do it.

It’s simple and easy. At first, you will define the breadcrumbs block. Then, you will add label, title and link to your breadcrumbs. ***The addCrumb Magento function is used in this case.***

`-->$breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs');
-->$breadcrumbs->addCrumb('home', array('label'=>Mage::helper('cms')->__('Home'), 'title'=>Mage::helper('cms')->__('Home Page'), 'link'=>Mage::getBaseUrl()));`
-->`$breadcrumbs->addCrumb('country', array('label'=>'Country', 'title'=>'All Countries', 'link'=>'http://example.com/magento/moduleName/country'));
-->$breadcrumbs->addCrumb('manufacturer', array('label'=>'State', 'title'=>'States'));
echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->toHtml();`